# ckfinder select multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, ckfinder

For a photo album I would like to use ckfinder to select (and upload if needed) what images you want to use within the photoalbum. But having to select one by one is obviously not the best user experience.

Is there any way where you can select multiple files (by either dragging or ctrl clicking) using ckfinder? I read the ckfinder API documentation but I can't seem to find anything about this. Is there maybe a plugin available for this or how would I go about making a plugin for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKFinder now supports this function, also see: http://cksource.com/blog/CKFinder_2.3_Released

Answer (score 1):

Currently CKFinder doesn't have such option.

You should add this request in the [CKFinder forums](http://cksource.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=10) so the developers realize how many people want it (I think that there should be already a thread about it, so you can add a "me too" there)

Comment: Yes, I already did a "me too" and asked how the development on this was going, since the last reply was a few months old. No answers so far yet though..

Answer (score 0):

CKFinder does support this function.

1. Click "Upload"
2. Ctrl select whatever images you want in your photo album
3. Click "Open"

And you are good to go.

If you are using the free version this may be the problem.

Go to http://ckfinder.com/demo and try out what I just said.

Comment: You are talking about the uploading part, I am talking about when you have files on the server and want to select more of them at the same time.

Comment: Ah I see... Well you did say "to select (and upload if needed)". Well hopefully it will help someone else.